# There was no endpoint listening at ... that could accept the message

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core, connected-services

I'm building an ASP.NET Core web API project.

Service runs sometimes, sometimes fails.

I get 90% successful results.

There was no endpoint listening at (url) that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

The binding is as follows

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The service should work improperly. By default, the invocation sent by a proxy preferentially uses the service URI generated in the reference.cs file.
[image]
We should change it to the practical service URL.

> https://vabqia96vm:21011/

Furthermore, the service communicates with the client is protected by the transport layer security. We should trust the server’s certificate before sending an invocation or add a procedure of SSL authentication to ignore validating the server's certificate.

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
//ignore the SSL authentication.            
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication=new System.ServiceModel.Security.X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
            {
                CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
                RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
            };
            var result = client.TestAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result.Result);
```

Also, we could call the service by using ChannelFactory.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://vabqia969vm:21011");
        BasicHttpsBinding binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
        factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication=new System.ServiceModel.Security.X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
        {
            CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
            RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
        };
        var client = factory.CreateChannel();
        var result = client.Test();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }


}
//the service contract is shared between the server-side and the client-side.
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Test();
}
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.